# Regex - How can I remove specific characters between strings/delimiters?

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

This is related to cleaning files before parsing them elsewhere, namely, malformed/ugly CSV. I see plenty of examples for removing/matching all characters between certain strings/characters/delimiters, but I cannot find any for specific strings. Example portion of line would look something like:

```
","Should now be allowed by rule above "Server - Access" added by Rich"\r
```

To be clear, this is not the entire line, but the entire line is enclosed in quotes and separated by "," and ends in ^M (Windows newline/carriage return).The 'columns' preceding this would be enclosed at each side by ",". I would probably use this too to remove cruft that appears earlier in the line.

What I am trying to get to is the removal of all double quotes between "," and "\r  ("Server - Access" - these ones) without removing the delimiters. Alternatively, I may just find and replace them with \" to delimit them for the Ruby CSV library. So far I have this:

```
(?<=",").*?(?="\\r)
```

Which basically matches everything between the delimiters. If I replace .*? with anything, be that a letter, double quotes etc, I get zero matches. What am I doing wrong?

Note: This should be Ruby compatible please.

Comment: Replace the match inside a block.

Comment: It's not something that can be done with a regex solely. You have to check to see how the start of the next line looks, then determine whether that line begins correctly or if it's the result of an embedded line-end. If it's because of an embedded line-end then you'll want to join the lines appropriately. This isn't an easy problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

```
text = '","Should now be allowed by rule above "Server - Access" added by Rich"\r'
puts text.gsub(/(?<!,)"(?![,\\r])/, '\"')
# ","Should now be allowed by rule above \"Server - Access\" added by Rich"\r
```

Of course, this won't work if the values themselves can contain comas and new lines...

Comment: Thats kind of why I need the delimiter to be ","  and then "\r (double quotes included) and not just the comma or \r. That way I know im not going to nuke anything within the column. I am already subbing comma's out and delimiting with a back slash to ensure the CSV library can output correctly.

Comment: What I meant was that if a comma can be a part of the string, there is no real guarantee you won't have a `","` as part of your string as well...

Comment: Ahh I get you. It is a bit of a running battle to be honest, but if I can parse 80% of these files that is a massive reduction in work for my team. This will never need to be client-facing of 100%. I'll give your solution a test run. Thanks!